# How do I select something from a sqlite3 table and assign it to a variable?

Tags: python, sqlite

how do I select a certain value from a sqlite3 table and assign it to a variable in my python script?
I know how to select, I just don't know how to assign it to the variable.

example:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT dinosaur, weight FROM table WHERE dinosaur=?", (dino,))
```

In this example, how do I assign the weight and dinosaur to variables that I can use in the rest of the script.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

A snippet for this is

```
cursor.execute("SELECT dinosaur, weight FROM table WHERE dinosaur=?", (dino,))
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Here rows will be a list of tuples of the form (dinosaur,weight)